# Is the specificity in CSS3 different than in CSS2.1?

Tags: css, inheritance, css-specificity

I have been reading up on specificity these days, and I find confusing some claims from the websites, especially from one which I find quite relevant (as far as other CSS materials go).

On this website http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ at the beginning of website author explains following:

```
<ul id="summer-drinks">
   **<li class="favorite">Whiskey and Ginger Ale</li>**
   <li>Wheat Beer</li>
   <li>Mint Julip</li>
</ul>
```

Now you pop open your CSS and do your styling for your new class:

```
.favorite {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

So the `<li>` tag with the class of favorite judging by the author shouldn't be red and bold as the class claims because the id `summer-drinks` is more specific the favorite class. But when I put this code I get the opposite result, `<li>` class with the favorite class is really bold and red? Always when I target child element who is inside of parent element who is more specific then the child element I get child styles as a result?

How is this happening? Does it have anything to do with the fact that I am using HTML Doctype and, therefore, CSS3 differs from CSS2.1?

Comment: The specificity rules have not changed. (Since the question *really* isn't about this, and *lacks any sort of credible test-case* with results from different CSS version implementations, please don't write such leading titles - just focus on the *actual* issue at hand.)

Comment: Did you also include his next example CSS block, the one that causes the trouble? The one that begins `ul#summer-drinks li {`?

Comment: Please note that HTML (for the `DOCTYPE html` part) and CSS specifications are orthogonal: you can use CSS3 with HTML4/xHTML and CSS2 with HTML5 and any other combination.

Comment: There is no rule using an id selector in the question.

Comment: Yes Paul Roub I didn't include the folllowing block ul#summer-drinks li, instead I 've just used #summer-drinks. Guys sorry I apologize in advance and thanks for your answers.